# print/output a jsp page from a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a header.jsp, menu.jsp and footer.jsp page. I now need to output a page from a servlet and want to include the header (which includes the menu) and the footer from the servlet before and after the servlet generated output.

It's homework and the page must be created by the servlet even though the logic is very simple. 
Note that using a templating system or anything else fancy would be overkill.

Is this possible and how?

Comment: BTW if you're using JSP then you're already using a templating system.

Comment: don't try to putput from servlet as you have dedicated jsp for this

Comment: I guess its better you first read some tutorials. Move your mouse over the jsp or servlets tag then wait for the dialog box to appear, then click the info. You will see there some guidelines you'll need. Also read something about MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
request.getRequestDipatcher('header.jsp').include(request,response);
```